# No module named traitlets.config.application

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have installed `ipython` through apt-get install ipython on Ubuntu 14.04 and my python version is 2.7.6. When I ran `ipython` in the console, I faced this error and I could not find any similar problems on any site. Can someone help me?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ipython", line 4, in <module>
    from IPython import start_ipython
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 22, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
ImportError: No module named traitlets.config.application
```

Comment: check to make sure your versions are correct. Have you installed pip and tried: pip install traitlets

Comment: apt-get should normally install all the dependencies. However there is something odd about this, because apt-get does not normally install into /usr/local  . It is possible the OP has 2 versions of python, or 2 versions of ipython, with a conflict.

Answer (score 7):

As @user3682792 says, just doing

```
sudo pip install traitlets
```

Fixed this issue for me. Thanks!

Comment: Normally pip is expected to correctly install dependencies of required packages.

Comment: Maybe `traitlets` was installed via the operating system package manager or conda and then uninstalled without `pip` knowing. I think that's what happened in my case, since I had done an `apt autoremove` just before getting this error. `pip install`ing traitlets fixed that error, but then I was also missing `pygments`, `pexpect`, and possibly more packages... I decided it would be easier to just uninstall and reinstall `ipython` with `pip`, and that took care of all of the dependencies automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I get this error because of my python version
it was 3.6 and I upgrade it to 3.8 and tadddaaaa :)
the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. In my case it was because I had a version of `ipython` in `~/.local/bin` and another one in my virtual environment, and because `~/.local/bin` appeared before my virtual environment bin in `$PATH`, it took precedence over the ipython my virtual environment.

So if you have the same issue as me, either change the $PATH variable or get rid of the `ipython` from `~/.local/bin`.

Answer (score -1):

If you got here more recently, I have updated to Ubuntu 21.04 but for some reason got this error. Lo and behold my python was still python 2. Then do this:

`sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3 10`

This gives python3 a higher priority than python2 when "python" is called. Fixed my problem; the traitlets error was coming from python2 running in ipython